# Video Streaming Website Development

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

This is the first time I am going to work on full-flagged video website development in my life and no idea about streaming technology and related stuffs.

I have no issue with html, css, js, php and other video or any art related tool and familiar with JW Player too.

Now my confusion are as below

1. How to create streaming video (preferred HTML5 to support all latest
   platform and devices)
2. Do I required streaming server to run video website? or just
   streaming video will be fine and can host on normal dedicated
   server?
3. What would be the best way to create full-flagged video website. Is
   wordpress is the good solution for large viewer? ( As I am much much
   familiar with wordpress)
4. What things I should mention while developing.

I am really hopping great help from you expert as before.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using JW PLayer HTML5 is automatic and they also offer their own streaming platform, bitsontherun, which will automatically resolve most of your issues. However, it's not cheap. Otherwise there are a number of issues you need to consider:

- how many streams you will serve/day
- total bandwidth
- do you want to protect videos from leeching, direct download, using in 3rd party sites or apps (increases your bandwidth cost)

I don't use wordpress, but in reading about different things, it seems like wordpress often has compatibility issues with newer video technologies. I would stay away from that if you can already do php , css, html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great feedback, I believe it will help me to start things in right direction. I am familiar with JW Player but never used bitsontherun so no idea about that. The website eventually will have huge amount of video and visitors too. But no exact count yet. My concern is to keep ready for some additional streams and bandwidth. I also may want to protect video from leeching, direct download

Comment: You might also want to consider FlowPlayer. Unless there is something very specific that you want in JWPlayer, Flow Player could be a better choice. It has a lot more plugins including, load balancing and clustering (if your site gets really big). On the other hand, if it gets really big you'll probably want a streaming server like Wowza, Flash Media Server or Red5. But it's not absolutely necessary, I currently run a site with a maximum of around 2000 streams/day and it runs fine on a VPS with my own php video scripts.

Comment: So you mean I should use flow player rather than jw player. I have no problem to adopt that. I need your suggestion what will be the server requirements if the site will have around 100 to 300 per day and 700 to 1000 visitors per day?

Comment: FlowPlayer has more plugins. You need to see which player meets your requirements. JWPlayer is a little easier to get running using the default setup. It could also have something that FlowPlayer doesn't that you want. They have similar features but not exact replacements for each other. For 100-300 streams and 1000 visitors per day you probably won't have any probem with a quality hosting solution, but it's impossible to say without having somebody look at exactly what you're doing.