# Multiple ipcam request can block the browser?

Tags: browser-cache

My situation (very simplified) is as follows :

- In a single page i have **n** ipcam objects. Every ipcam object has its own div , where the image of the ipcam is updated each time the previous image is received.
- a javascript function call a php file (passing the id of the ipcam as parameter) that return the image with a socket request (after picking the settings for that particular id [ip, port, authentication, username, password etc etc]).

Javascript code (simplified)

```
//called by a timer 
function refresh_ipcam(id){

    if(parseInt($("#"+id).attr('refresh_finished')) == 1){

        $("#"+id).attr('refresh_finished',0);

        var img = new Image(....);
        var x = new Date().getTime();
        img.src = "get_image.php?id="+id+"&random="+x;

        img.onload = function(){
            $("#"+id).html(img);
            $("#"+id).attr('refresh_finished',1);
        }
        img.onerror = function(e){
            setTimeout(function(e){
                $("#"+id).attr('refresh_finished',1);
            },2000)
        }
    }
}
```

By adding the random parameter, the browser always detects a new image. In this way i solved a problem (the image was not updated correctly for cache issues). But i think there is another kind of problem in this way, given the high number of requests made.

Some user have reported the block of the browser (after some time). Can this be a problem related to a full cache?

From the google chrome console , in the *Application > Frames > Images* section, i noticed that every request (get_image.php) matches a new element in this list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like solutions based on image source manipulation do not work well. They use a lot of memory and may even crash browser. Probably you need to consider [live streaming web video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video).

For more information check:

- [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url) discussion, and Aya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943419/2594597) in particular.
- [Could the HTML 5 Video tag source come from streaming IP cam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287933/could-the-html-5-video-tag-source-come-from-streaming-ip-cam) discussion
- [Video Streaming Website Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439775/video-streaming-website-development?rq=1) discussion
- [36142 - manipulating img src via javascript will generate a massive memory leak](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142) and [570268 - ImageResource keeps memory alive without telling v8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570268) Chromium bugs